# How to add animation to the input field by using animate css class if form validation fails

Tags: angular

Instead of your name is required I want that `animated pulse` classes should be added to the input field. Both these classes are from animate.css library which displays pulse effect and the class should also be removed once the user enters a valid text to reset the animation so that the animation shows again if the user does something wrong on that input field agin.

```
<form method="post" [formGroup]="registerForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <input type="text" formControlName="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name *"/>
    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.first_name.errors && registerForm.controls.first_name.touched" class="error">
    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.first_name.errors.required">Your name is required</div>
    </div>
     <div *ngIf="submitted && registerForm.controls.first_name.errors && registerForm.controls.first_name.pristine" class="error">
    <div *ngIf="registerForm.controls.first_name.errors.required">Your name is required</div>
    </div>
```

.ts

```
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          first_name: ['', Validators.required],

 onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    if (this.registerForm.invalid) {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ngClass directive` to dynamically add or remove class to html tags. Based on the code you provided i am guessing you want to add class when input field is touched. You achieve this with reactive form control property `touched` and `invalid`.

`<input [ngClass]="{'animated pulse': registerForm.get('first_name').touched && registerForm.get('first_name').invalid}" type="text" formControlName="first_name" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name *"/>`

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, could you please add some commentary as to what this code does and how it solves the original question.